# How to curve mesh in multiple axis at the same time?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to build the bottom part of this japanese lantern but I am unable to replicate the curvature of the base where the letters are written.

[image]

So far I have achieved the following trying to align the vertex along the Y axis, however, as you can imagine, they are not aligned in the X one at the same time, so I would require to do the process twice. Is there a way to do it at the same time? I tried with Proportional Editing with no avail :(

[image]

Comment: Select a horizontal edge loop in the middle of the column and then set the Proportional editing dropdown to 'Sphere' befores scaling the loop. If you need more details, just comment and I'll post an answer later.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That did the trick. I forgot to disable the Connected only check, which was messing around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much what John Eason said in the comment: *Proportional Editing* with *Sphere* falloff, bevel on hard edges:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @Markus Thanks for saving me the trouble. - I had to go to lunch or there would be two identical answers! :^)